# where is the cut plane for Forge levels extension?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-bim360

for Forge Autodesk.AEC.LevelsExtension, where is the cut plane? looks like it doesn't follow the view range in Revit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Appended to what Cyrille mentioned.

Revit's AEC model data will be generated automatically during the Forge translation. The [level info](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/add-data-visualization-heatmaps-rooms-non-revit-model-part-i-nwc) is dumping from Revit Level elements, e.g., the name, guid, elevations, extensions of the Revit Level which you can see with Revit API. The Levels extension just uses it to rebuild level ranges.

For example, the cutting range of level 1 will be from level1's elevation to (level2's elevation - a height adjustment) with my research. The height adjustment is to avoid cutting on top of floors to brining a better view. So, it's not following Revit's view range of the floor plan view.

If the levels extension doesn't match your need, you may check out my [level section tool](https://github.com/yiskang/forge-au-sample/blob/master/level-section/scripts/AdnLevelSectionPanel.js). This sample demonstrates the concept of how to create cut planes by levels.

[image: View on Youtube]

Comment: thanks Eason, looks like level section extension default cut plane is level above, means for F1 section, we will see F2 top floor slab which is not desired even though i can adjust it via OOTB Section Analysis, now i have to figure out how to make that default cut plane a bit lower than F2 top floor slab, obviously view range won't work as it is plan view related not floor related.

Comment: You can hide objects of levelOccluderIds of the AEC Model Data to hide floors or ceilings that are placed near upper-level lines, and recalculate the z value of upper cut plane, e.g. the elevation of the upper level - a thickness of the floor/slab.

Comment: thanks Eason, that's what i want to achieve, but how to access them from Autodesk.AEC.LevelsExtension or Autodesk.AEC.Hypermodeling or Autodesk.ADN.SheetsBrowserExt?

Comment: There is no documented way, but you can get floor data via the `levelsExt.selector. floorData` and update back to `levelsExt` by using `levelsExt.selector.floorData = newFloorData`. Since it's a non-documented way, you may use it at your own risk.

Comment: Or Consider using the above sample I shared to do so.

Comment: looks like levelSelector.floorData can only get floor bounding box as mentioned by Cyrille i.e. name: "02 - Floor", zMin: -3.8906222135343196, zMax: 8.65990272084374, what exactly does zMin/zMax means here? i assume it's bottom/top elevations of that floor slab in feet, but looks like that's not the case?!

Comment: yes Eason, i need to dive into your sample you just shared, thanks again!

Comment: hi Jason, seems i cannot run your (AU) sample, did i miss something?

Comment: It requests data from the backend at [L#128](https://github.com/yiskang/forge-au-sample/blob/master/level-section/scripts/AdnLevelSectionPanel.js#L128). You can see the data structure [here](https://github.com/yiskang/forge-au-sample/blob/master/mock-server/db.json#L161)

Comment: As I know, the zMin of the floor data is the elevation of the level in feet, and the zMax is `the upper level's elevation - an adjustment` as I mentioned above.

Comment: thanks Eason, if zMin and zMax are the 2 levels' elevation, then that makes my life much easier - no need to get level elevation from getAecModelData()

Comment: looks like only ground level works for the following code: this.viewer.setCutPlanes([new THREE.Vector4(0,0,1,level.zMax)], [new THREE.Vector4(0,0,1,level.zMin)]); also tried the below: this.viewer.setCutPlanes([new THREE.Vector4(0,0,1,level.zMax - GobalOffset.z)], [new THREE.Vector4(0,0,1,level.zMin - GobalOffset.z)]); did i miss something simple?!

Comment: ok, figured out, should be this.viewer.setCutPlanes([new THREE.Vector4(0,0,1,-1*level.zMax)], [new THREE.Vector4(0,0,-1,level.zMin)]); thanks again Eason!

Comment: hi Jason, from your previous comments "For example, the cutting range of level 1 will be from level1's elevation to (level2's elevation - a height adjustment) with my research. The height adjustment is to avoid cutting on top of floors to brining a better view. So, it's not following Revit's view range of the floor plan view.", what is the default value of height adjustment and how to get access and change that value? besides, most of time that height adjustment doesn't work (cut plane is still at top surface of upper level floor slab), it only worked once on my side, seems unstable?!

Answer (score 1):

In this extension, floors cut planes are defined based on the bounding box of the floor node in the scene instance tree. Floors are defined in an additional AEC data json file which contains additional information.

Comment: you mean floor above? for instance, for level 1, its cut plane is level 2 floor, looks like floor top instead of floor bottom which makes more sense, in fact, reflecting view range of Revit makes most sense, anyway, how to define that additional AEC data json file in floor node? or even better define on the fly via coding